# How to calculate correlation coefficient between a discrete variable and a binary (0, 1) variable

Tags: python, pandas

I am now working on a pandas dataframe (mxn) like the following:

```
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5  Xn-1 Y
0    a b c d e f ... a    0
1    e c a a b b ... c    1
2    d e f a c c ... f    1
.    ...   ....  ... .    .
.    ...   ....  ... .    .
.    ...   ....  ... .    .
m-1  f b c d a a ... c    0
```

Columns X1 to (n-1) consist of letters ‘a', 'b', 'c', 'd' or 'f', The column ['Y'] consists of binary 0 or 1.

Now I want to caluculate the correlation coefficient between each Xi and Y, which alogrithmn should I use? should I use the Kendall tu? However, it seems that kendall tu apply to varialbes with certain rank order, such as X=[1,2,3,4,5], Y=[3,5,7,9,11], but my data don't have any rank order. The 'a','b','c','d','e','f' and '0','1' are totally independent to each other. Can kendall method be apply to this situation? This there better method that can be applied?

I hyperthosize kendall tu can be apply and use the follow codes to calculte the correlation:

```
les = []
  x = data[:,:n-1]
  for i in range(x.shape[1]):
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(x.iloc[:,i])
    les.append(le)
    x.iloc[:,i] = le.transform(x.iloc[:, i])

for i in range(x.shape[1]):
    print "site = ", cols[i]
    df['X'] = x.iloc[:,i]
    corr = df.corr(method='kendall')
    corr_value.append(corr.iloc[0,1])
```

I find the correlation coefficient is 'nan' for some Xi, why?

Could you help me with this problems? Thank you in advance!